# inner nested shortcodes not working - eg: columns not showing inside of row

Tags: wordpress, nested, row, shortcode

I wanted to create specially styled columns, but make it easy for the client to still edit the content of the column.. so I created my own shortcodes to setup the row and columns inside. (This is a custom wordpress template I created for a specific client).

Here is the code in my function.php for the two shortcodes 'member-row' & 'member':

```
    add_shortcode('member-row', function ($content = null) {
        return '<div class="row">
        <br />'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
    });


    add_shortcode('member', function ($atts, $content = null) {
       extract(shortcode_atts(array(
          'color' => 'white',
       ), $atts));
        return '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 md-margin-bottom-40">
    <div class="member-col funny-boxes funny-boxes-top-'.$color.'">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>
    </div>';
    });
```

I've also added the `.do_shortcode($content).` on the inner-nested 'member' column shortcode - just in case the client wants to add other shortcodes inside of each column. (Note: The problem still occurs even if I change the 'member' shortcode to just use `.$content.`)

Here is the code I entered in the **text** side of the wordpress page editor

```
    [member-row]
    [member color="gold"]

    <a href="http://www.example1.com/"><img class="aligncenter img-responsive" src="http://localhost/test/testWP/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logo1.jpg" alt="logo" /></a>
    <strong>Company 1</strong>
    Address
    Telephone
    <a href="http://www.example1.com/" target="_blank">www.example1.com</a>

    [/member][member color="yellow"]

    <a href="http://www.example2.com/"><img class="aligncenter  img-responsive" src="http://localhost/test/testWP/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logo2.jpg" alt="logo" /></a>
    <strong>Company 2</strong>
    Address
    Telephone
    <a href="http://www.example2.com/" target="_blank">www.example2.com</a>

    [/member]
    [/member-row]
```

When I save, and click on 'view page', the section where this has been added doesn't display anything.

This is the html code that is produced:

```
    <div class="row">
    <br /></div>
```

So it is only executing the 'member-row' shortcode, and not the nested 'member' shortcode columns.

This is the correct html code I was expecting:

```
    <div class="row">
    <br />
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 md-margin-bottom-40">
    <div class="member-col funny-boxes funny-boxes-top-gold">
    <a href="http://www.example1.com/"><img class="aligncenter img-responsive" src="http://localhost/test/testWP/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logo1.jpg" alt="logo" /></a>
    <strong>Company 1</strong>
    Address
    Telephone
    <a href="http://www.example1.com/" target="_blank">www.example1.com</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 md-margin-bottom-40">
    <div class="member-col funny-boxes funny-boxes-top-yellow">
    <a href="http://www.example2.com/"><img class="aligncenter img-responsive" src="http://localhost/test/testWP/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/logo2.jpg" alt="logo" /></a>
    <strong>Company 2</strong>
    Address
    Telephone
    <a href="http://www.example2.com/" target="_blank">www.example2.com</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

When I just remove the surrounding `[member-row]` and `[/member-row]` shortcodes from the editor window, then the 'member' column shortcode **does** show up properly on the webpage.. so it appears it is ***just being inside*** of the 'member-row' shortcode that causes the problem.

Note: I did try adding the `add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode', 10);` line to the bottom of my function.php file, but it didn't seem to make any difference, so I removed it.

Hopefully I have just made some typo error.. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: no @vrajesh.. this is a different problem.  From the question I asked previously (see the link you provided), and with a little more research, I learned how to add an enclosing shortcode that allows me to have a start and end tag in the page editor like [box] and [/box] correctly.  I have used that info above in the new short code I am creating.. but this time I am dealing with nested shortcodes.. which is where my problem is occuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

I had to add `$atts` to the function for the member-row shortcode as follows:

```
add_shortcode('member-row', function ($atts, $content = null) {
return '<div class="row">
<br />'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
});
```

It now works as expected!!

I am not sure why I needed to add `$atts`, as this shortcode is not passing attributes or setting default ones, but it appears you need it if you are going to use enclosing shortcode with `$content`.  (Maybe it is needed because `$content` is defined as the 'second' parameter???)

I just read in the WP Codex for shortcode api that

> "Three parameters `{$atts, $content, $tag}` are passed to the shortcode
>   callback function. You can choose to use any number of them including
>   none of them."

So that seems to me that you could use the `$content` by itself... but as I just proved that `$content` can't be by itself - I am still unsure of the reason that my solution worked for me.  (Just glad it did!)

If anyone knows the rule or reason for why the `$atts` is needed to make this work, I would appreciate the comment - to clarify this for myself, and anyone else that has the same problem.

Thanks!